# Redirect Form to Home after submit - Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect the user to the homepage after submitting the registration form but seem to be stuck. I know you can utilize `return HttpResponseRedirect('/')` but is there a way to incorporate that inline with `return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})`

```
# Signup Form
def signup(request):   
    form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
        user = User.objects.create(email=email)
        user_type = request.POST.get('user_type')

        # create jobseeker or company object
        if user_type == "jobseeker":
            jobseeker = JobSeeker.objects.create(user=user)
        else:
        # if user_type == "company":
        company = Company.objects.create(user=user)
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: why is the return statement outside the signup function scope?

Comment: It shouldn't be. That was a formatting issue when posting it. Revised the OP.

Comment: You cannot share context between views with a redirect, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```css
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

# Signup Form
def signup(request):   
 form = UserCreationForm()
 if request.method == "POST":
  email = request.POST.get('email')
  password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
  password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
  user = User.objects.create(email=email)
  user_type = request.POST.get('user_type')

  # create jobseeker or company object
  if user_type == "jobseeker":
   jobseeker = JobSeeker.objects.create(user=user)
  else:
  # if user_type == "company":
  company = Company.objects.create(user=user)
  return reverse_lazy('home')
 return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```